# Command line binary for VMWare Fusion location?

Tags: command-line, vmware-fusion

I use VMware on Linux quite extensively, and I am wondering where/what the equivalent of 'VMware-cmd' is on Fusion. I would like to be able to start/stop VM's, without the GUI (If possible).

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of interesting stuff in  **/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion**  (at least with fusion2).  vmrun is the command that should let you manipulate running vms.  I've used vmrun pretty heavily on linux, but never on fusion, so ymmv